# Create SQL Server stored procedure to act like a "Contains"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that currently returns the value form a column that the query equals.

```
@CUST_NAME = CUST_NAME
```

I now need it to act more like (pseudocode)

```
 (column) CUST_NAME CONTAINS (variable) @CUST_NAME
```

So essentially, if the search is 'smith' it will return all smiths from the column as well as all 'smithson'.

Current stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGet_Account_Numbers_From_Name]
    @CUST_NAME AS VARCHAR(36)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1
        CAST(CAST([TAOAB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER] AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TA_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        CAST(CAST([FTPAB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER] AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FTB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        [CUSTOMER_SSN]
    FROM 
        [AccountConversion]
    WHERE
        @CUST_NAME = CUST_NAME
END
```

Comment: `CUST_NAME LIKE '%'+@CUST_NAME+'%'`

Comment: Google "SQL LIKE OPERATOR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the "CONTAINS" keyword unless the column is full-text indexed.

If you wish to do partial string matching, you can do something like this instead:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGet_Account_Numbers_From_Name] @CUST_NAME AS VARCHAR(36)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        CAST(CAST([TAOAB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER] AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TA_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        CAST(CAST([FTPAB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER] AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FTB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        [CUSTOMER_SSN]
    FROM 
        [AccountConversion]
    WHERE
        CUST_NAME LIKE '%' + @CUST_NAME + '%'
END
```